# make install using a conda environement

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile, anaconda

I'm trying to install [HaploStrips](https://bitbucket.org/dmarnetto/haplostrips/src/master/), which requires python 2.7 and pip (and a few other libraries). The author suggests to create an anaconda environment using `conda create -n haplostrips python=2.7 pandas=0.22 pysam`, then activating that environment and installing using that.

However, even when I do that, the installer can't find pandas or pysam, or the correct version of Python (it uses my default python install, which is 3.8).

How can I get `make install` to use the executables provided by anaconda? Is there a better way to get it to use python 2.7 + the other dependancies?

This is the output from running `conda create --name haplostripsb python=2.7`:

```
 >> conda create --name haplostripsb python=2.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1216): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
install(args, parser, 'create')
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 260, in install
unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 435, in _collect_all_metadata
_supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 164, in _supplement_index_with_system
dist_name, dist_version = context.os_distribution_name_version
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 863, in os_distribution_name_version
from conda._vendor.distro import id, version
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
_distro = LinuxDistribution()
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
self._lsb_release_info = self._get_lsb_release_info() \
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1214, in print_unexpected_error_report
message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 237, in get_main_info_str
info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 87, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
install(args, parser, 'create')
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 260, in install
unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 435, in _collect_all_metadata
_supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 164, in _supplement_index_with_system
dist_name, dist_version = context.os_distribution_name_version
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 863, in os_distribution_name_version
from conda._vendor.distro import id, version
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1084, in <module>
_distro = LinuxDistribution()
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 599, in __init__
self._lsb_release_info = self._get_lsb_release_info() \
File "/home/muthur/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 943, in _get_lsb_release_info
raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.
`$ /home/muthur/anaconda3/bin/conda create --name haplostripsb python=2.7`
environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

This is the output from running `lsb_release -a`

```
 >> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Does just running `conda create --name haplostrips python=2.7` work? If not, please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo tried to create that env, and got a big error message: https://pastebin.com/rhLdA2h5 `conda --version` works fine and tells me it's 4.12.0, if that's of any use. I'll restart and try again, see if that changes anything. EDIT: restarted my Ubuntu VM (WSL2) and nothing changed

Comment: What Linux distro are you using? Also, what is the output of `lsb_release -a`?